# Getting password prompted when running kubectl commands

Tags: kubernetes

I inherited a couple server running Kubernetes.  And one of the things secops wants me to do is install an agent on the server.  One of the first commands to run is

```
kubectl create secret generic
```

Running this, I am prompted for username and password.  No one here knows what this is b/c the dev who set up the server is gone.  So I don't know how to run this command and get passed the username/password.  An obvious suggestion from someone else was using default user/pass but I can't even find that online.  Found this to help get info on the server:

```
kubectl config view
```

Output of this command:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null

Server:
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009
Kernel - 5.17.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that your Kubernetes cluster is set up to support username/password combination. Is this setup installed using kubeadm? Maybe you could copy the `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` from your master node and use it as your kubeconfig (if it's there).

Answer (score 0):

It is plausible that the kubeconfig file you are using is corrupt.  You can reproduce similar symptoms(user/pass prompt) by editing the user name in your kubeconfig file. You need to find out(or create) the right kubeconfig file for the user. If you are an admin, you can find it at `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` in the master node.

Here are steps to reproduce the issue:

// This is my kubeconfig file, working fine

```
kubectl config view 
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

// I searched for the user name

```
kubectl config view  |grep 'user: default'
    user: default
```

// corrupted the user name from `default` to `default1`

```
sed -i.bak 's/user: default/user: default1/g' ~/.kube/config
```

// now getting prompted for user/password

```
kubectl get pod  --kubeconfig .kube/config 
Please enter Username: 
^C
```

//reverted the changes done earlier

```
sed -i 's/user: default1/user: default/g' ~/.kube/config
```

// commands working fine now

```
kubectl get pod  --kubeconfig .kube/config 
No resources found in default namespace.
```